# How can I move this text to the top

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation with unordered list, I made the `li` display to be inline, And here comes the problem, I am having problem trying to align the text upward, apparently, inline elements doesn't take `margin` and `padding` property.

My codes:

```
  <ul>
       <li><a href="#"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><h3>About</h3></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><h3>Contacr</h3></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><h3>Blog</h3></a></li>
 </ul>
```

```css
       ul{
            list-style: none;
         max-width: 250px;
         height: 40px;
         background-color: #486348;
         margin-top: 20px;
         padding: 0;
         padding-right: 10px;
         padding-bottom: 10px;
         padding-top: -10px;
      }

       li{
           display: inline-block;
        height: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 0;
        border: 1px solid rgba(78,78,78,0.67);
        } 

      a {
           color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 1;
      }
```

```html
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><h3>About</h3></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><h3>Contacr</h3></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><h3>Blog</h3></a></li>
     </ul>
```

Although a line-height of 1 did do something nice for me, but not enough, so how do I move my text upward neatly?

Comment: Write semantic HTML. Your sub-sub-headings are being headings for anything. Take the h3 elements out.

Comment: use line-height

Comment: if i take the h3 out, wouldn't that affect the format i desired?

Comment: please what really do you mean by write semantic HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your stylesheet add `h3 { margin:0; }`. The `h3` elements inside the anchors have a default `margin` value.

Also, to align the text in the middle (vertical alignment), add `line-height: 40px; display:block;` for the `a` elements, so they have the same `line-height` as their parent `li`.

Comment: you are very helpful, just got the problem solved. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! As Quentin said, you should write more semantic code. You can remove the `h3` elements from the navigation and you can also wrap your list inside a `nav` tag.

Comment: Means to use the proper `html` tags for each type of content. You can start reading here: http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/